# Reading ugly csv with tons of commas csvhelper

Tags: c#, csv, csvhelper

I have a csv file which looks like this:

```
,"CompanyNane",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,Issue,,,,2021-02-27,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,Inspection Sheet  ,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,<Sub>,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,1/200,,,,page,,,,,
,Delivery No.,,,,,,,,SDK2302278101,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,W No.,,,,,,,,AFC1210-22SL,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,Manufacturer,,,,,,,,ManufacturerCompanyName,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,Diameter,,,,,,,,6in,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,Poly-type/Conductivity,,,,,,,,4H/n-type,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,face/Orientation,,,,,,,,Si/(0001) 4deg off,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,Surface Finish,,,,,,,,CMP,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,"Coordinate data (X, Y) (mm)",,,,,,,,,,,,,Thickness (um),,,,,,,,Carrier Conc. (cm-3),,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,(,,,", ",,,),,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,(,0,,", ",70.0,,),,,,,14.67,,,,,,,,6829484552804830,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,14.67
,,,,,,,(,0,,", ",60.0,,),,,,,15.18,,,,,,,,7269218633966170,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,15.18
,,,,,,,(,0,,", ",45.0,,),,,,,15.35,,,,,,,,7101511576788490,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,15.35
,,,,,,,(,0,,", ",30.0,,),,,,,15.32,,,,,,,,6874133261805120,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,15.32
,,,,,,,(,0,,", ",15.0,,),,,,,15.2,,,,,,,,6701359170793300,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,15.2
,,,,,,,(,0,,", ",0.0,,),,,,,15.13,,,,,,,,6638519222094540,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,15.13
,,,,,,,(,0,,", ",-15.0,,),,,,,-,,,,,,,,-,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,(,0,,", ",-30.0,,),,,,,-,,,,,,,,-,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,(,0,,", ",-45.0,,),,,,,-,,,,,,,,-,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,(,0,,", ",-60.0,,),,,,,-,,,,,,,,-,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,(,0,,", ",-67.0,,),,,,,15.04,,,,,,,,7104368264503040,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,15.04
,,,,,,,(,,,", ",,,),,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,(,,,", ",,,),,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,(,-70,,", ",0.0,,),,,,,14.54,,,,,,,,6828523559220620,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,14.54
,,,,,,,(,-60,,", ",0.0,,),,,,,-,,,,,,,,-,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,(,-45,,", ",0.0,,),,,,,-,,,,,,,,-,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,(,-30,,", ",0.0,,),,,,,-,,,,,,,,-,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,(,-15,,", ",0.0,,),,,,,-,,,,,,,,-,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,(,15,,", ",0.0,,),,,,,-,,,,,,,,-,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,(,30,,", ",0.0,,),,,,,-,,,,,,,,-,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,(,45,,", ",0.0,,),,,,,-,,,,,,,,-,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,(,60,,", ",0.0,,),,,,,-,,,,,,,,-,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,(,70,,", ",0.0,,),,,,,14.65,,,,,,,,6866040706547180,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,14.65
,,,,,,,(,,,", ",,,),,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,Ave.,,,,,,,,,,,,,15.15,,,,,,,,6950000000000000,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,Uniformity(sigma/Ave.),,,,,,,,,,,,,1.6,,,,,%,,,3.1,,,,,,%,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,MAX,,,,,,,,,,,,,15.35,,,,,,,,7270000000000000,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,MIN,,,,,,,,,,,,,14.54,,,,,,,,6640000000000000,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

I honestly don't even know where to begin, I have no control over this csv file, as it is an incoming file from elsewhere, surely there is a way to replace these commas somehow? I understand this data is very ugly, the top line, I need the issue with the date, then starting at the  line, I need all data from that point forward.

The lines:

```
,<Sub>,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,1/200,,,,page,,,,,
,Delivery No.,,,,,,,,SDK2302278101,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,W No.,,,,,,,,AFC1210-22SL,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,Manufacturer,,,,,,,,ManufacturerCompanyName,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,Diameter,,,,,,,,6in,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,Poly-type/Conductivity,,,,,,,,4H/n-type,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,face/Orientation,,,,,,,,Si/(0001) 4deg off,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,Surface Finish,,,,,,,,CMP,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

Have their data horizontally, normally I can do this, just not with all those commas, it makes their indexes all different!

The lines:

```
,,,,,"Coordinate data (X, Y) (mm)",,,,,,,,,,,,,Thickness (um),,,,,,,,Carrier Conc. (cm-3),,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,(,,,", ",,,),,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,(,0,,", ",70.0,,),,,,,14.67,,,,,,,,6829484552804830,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,14.67
,,,,,,,(,0,,", ",60.0,,),,,,,15.18,,,,,,,,7269218633966170,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,15.18
,,,,,,,(,0,,", ",45.0,,),,,,,15.35,,,,,,,,7101511576788490,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,15.35
,,,,,,,(,0,,", ",30.0,,),,,,,15.32,,,,,,,,6874133261805120,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,15.32
,,,,,,,(,0,,", ",15.0,,),,,,,15.2,,,,,,,,6701359170793300,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,15.2
,,,,,,,(,0,,", ",0.0,,),,,,,15.13,,,,,,,,6638519222094540,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,15.13
,,,,,,,(,0,,", ",-15.0,,),,,,,-,,,,,,,,-,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,(,0,,", ",-30.0,,),,,,,-,,,,,,,,-,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,(,0,,", ",-45.0,,),,,,,-,,,,,,,,-,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,(,0,,", ",-60.0,,),,,,,-,,,,,,,,-,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,(,0,,", ",-67.0,,),,,,,15.04,,,,,,,,7104368264503040,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,15.04
,,,,,,,(,,,", ",,,),,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,(,,,", ",,,),,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,(,-70,,", ",0.0,,),,,,,14.54,,,,,,,,6828523559220620,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,14.54
,,,,,,,(,-60,,", ",0.0,,),,,,,-,,,,,,,,-,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,(,-45,,", ",0.0,,),,,,,-,,,,,,,,-,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,(,-30,,", ",0.0,,),,,,,-,,,,,,,,-,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,(,-15,,", ",0.0,,),,,,,-,,,,,,,,-,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,(,15,,", ",0.0,,),,,,,-,,,,,,,,-,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,(,30,,", ",0.0,,),,,,,-,,,,,,,,-,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,(,45,,", ",0.0,,),,,,,-,,,,,,,,-,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,(,60,,", ",0.0,,),,,,,-,,,,,,,,-,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,(,70,,", ",0.0,,),,,,,14.65,,,,,,,,6866040706547180,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,14.65
,,,,,,,(,,,", ",,,),,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,Ave.,,,,,,,,,,,,,15.15,,,,,,,,6950000000000000,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,Uniformity(sigma/Ave.),,,,,,,,,,,,,1.6,,,,,%,,,3.1,,,,,,%,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,MAX,,,,,,,,,,,,,15.35,,,,,,,,7270000000000000,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,MIN,,,,,,,,,,,,,14.54,,,,,,,,6640000000000000,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

These lines are like a traditional csv with a header at the top and the data underneath, but again, the commas make this real tricky. Any help would be appreciated! Just trying to get this data into a list.

Here's my current code:

```
class CsvHelperTester
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            var csvConfig = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
            {
                HasHeaderRecord = false,
                HeaderValidated = null,
                IgnoreBlankLines = true,
                MissingFieldFound = null,
                AllowComments = true,
                Comment = ';',
                Delimiter = ",",
                TrimOptions = TrimOptions.Trim,
                
            };
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader("C:filestuff"))
            {
                using (var csv = new CsvReader(streamReader, csvConfig))
                {

                    var records = new List<GeneralData>();


                    while (csv.Read())
                    {
                        if (csv.GetField(1) == "")
                        {
                            csv.Read();
                        }
                        records.Add(csv.GetRecord<GeneralData>());
                    }

                    var WRecords = csv.GetRecords<WData>().ToList();
                    var columns = records;

                }
            }
        }
        public class GeneralData
        {
            [Index(1)]
            public string Type { get; set; }
            [Index(2)]
            public string Value { get; set; }
        }
        public class WData
        {
            public string Coordinate_Data { get; set; }
        }

    }
```

I tried to make 2 lists, 1 for the horizontal data, and 1 for the traditional csv data, but was unsuccessful

Comment: Are you looking for a way to replace all the repeated commas with single ones?

Comment: As long as all the fields you care about are in the same place in each record I wouldn't worry about how many commas there are. If you want field 1, 56, and 117 then read those.

Comment: @Marsroverr yes if thats possible!

Comment: It looks like as if someone converted an excel with custom format file to csv, if you open the file with excel or sheets, it looks like a regular excel file

Comment: @Manuvo, I've never heard of a "custom format file", and quick search didn't turn up anything. Can you share a link to what that is/how it works? Thank you.

Comment: @ZachYoung Apologies for the confusion, what I meant by that is an excel file formatted in such manner that is not meant to be exported as a csv file (has many extra or hidden columns, merged cells, etc), e.g something like an invoice: [link to an example](https://www.exceldemy.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/tax-invoice-format-in-excel-1.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bit ugly but I think you can use a combination of looking for known stopping points along with data classes that use indexing to find their columns.

```cs
void Main()
{
    var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    {
        HasHeaderRecord = false
    };
    
    using (var reader = new StreamReader("C:filestuff"))
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, config))
    {
        csv.Read();
        var company = csv.GetField(1);
        var issue = csv.GetField(29);
        var issueDate = csv.GetField(33);
        
        var topData = new List<TopData>();
        var coordinateData = new List<CoordinateData>();
        var summaryData = new List<SummaryData>();
        
        // Skip to <Sub>
        while (csv.Read() && csv.GetField(1) != "<Sub>") { }
        
        // Read Horizontal data
        while (csv.Read() && csv.GetField(5) != "Coordinate data (X, Y) (mm)")
        {
            if (csv.GetField(1) != string.Empty)
                topData.Add(csv.GetRecord<TopData>());
        }

        // Read Coordinate data
        while (csv.Read() && csv.GetField(5) != "Ave.")
        {
            if (csv.GetField(8) != string.Empty)
                coordinateData.Add(csv.GetRecord<CoordinateData>());
        }
        
        // Read Summary data
        summaryData.Add(csv.GetRecord<SummaryData>());
        while (csv.Read())
        {
            summaryData.Add(csv.GetRecord<SummaryData>());
        }
    }
}

public class TopData
{
    [Index(1)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Index(9)]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class SummaryData
{
    [Index(5)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Index(18)]
    public string Value1 { get; set; }
    [Index(26)]
    public string Value2 { get; set; }
}

public class CoordinateData
{
    [Index(8)]
    public string X { get; set; }
    [Index(11)]
    public string Y { get; set; }
    [Index(18)]
    public string Mm { get; set; }
    [Index(26)]
    public string Thickness { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: this looks like it should work, but when I try I get nothing, maybe I'm putting a breakpoint in the wrong place? ```  while (csv.Read())
        {
            summaryData.Add(csv.GetRecord<SummaryData>());
        }
    }   ``` I put it in the 2nd closed brace

Comment: You should see most of the data there, but only 2 of the 4 `summaryData` items.  You should be able to see everything if you put a break on the next closing brace, the one that closes the `using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, config))`.  Inside the `while` loops where it is adding records, you might try something like this to see what columns your data is on. `Console.WriteLine($"row: {csv.Context.Parser.RawRow}"); for (int i = 0; i < csv.Context.Parser.Record.Count(); i++) { Console.WriteLine($" column: {i} - {csv.GetField(i)}"); }`  Make sure it matches the indexes I selected.

Answer (score 2):

To replace all the repeated commas with a single one use [Regex.Replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace?view=net-7.0)

Get the CSV file as a string then use:

```
string result = Regex.Replace(csvString, ",+", ",");
```

Finally, convert the resulting string back to CSV

Comment: I would suggest using `",,+"` or `",{2,}"` for the pattern for a slight increase in efficiency - no reason to replace "," with ","...

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution.  You only had one sample of the input so my code probably will need some tweaks before it will work on entire input.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;



namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {

        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.csv";
        public enum State
        {
            NONE,
            GET_DELIVERY,
            GET_PART
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FILENAME);
            string line = "";
            List<Delivery> deliveries = new List<Delivery>();
            Delivery delivery = null;
            Part part = null;
            State state = State.NONE;
            while((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                line = line.Trim(new char[] { ' ', ',' });
                if(line.Length > 0)
                {
                    if(line.StartsWith("<Sub>"))
                    {
                        state = State.GET_DELIVERY;
                        delivery = new Delivery();
                        deliveries.Add(delivery);
                        continue;
                    }
                    if (line.StartsWith("\"Coordinate data"))
                    {
                        //do nothing
                        continue;
                    }    
                    switch (state)
                    {
                        case State.GET_DELIVERY:
                            if (line == "(,,,\", \",,,)")
                            {
                                state = State.GET_PART;
                                part = new Part();
                                if (delivery.parts == null) delivery.parts = new List<Part>();
                                delivery.parts.Add(part);
                                continue;
                            }
                            delivery.AddProperty(line);
                            break;
                        case State.GET_PART:
                            if (line == "(,,,\", \",,,)")
                            {
                                state = State.GET_DELIVERY;
                                continue;
                            }
                            part.AddPoint(line);
                            break;
                    }
                }

            }

        }
    }
    public class Delivery
    {
        public string deliverNo { get; set; }
        public string wNo { get; set; }
        public string manufacturer { get; set; }
        public string diameter { get; set; }
        public string pTypeConductivity { get; set; }
        public string faceOrientation { get; set; }
        public string surfaceFinish { get; set; }
        public decimal average { get; set; }
        public decimal uniformitySigma { get; set; }
        public decimal uniformityAve { get; set; }
        public decimal max { get; set; }
        public decimal min { get; set; }
        public List<Part> parts { get; set; }

        public void AddProperty(string line)
        {
            string[] splitArray = line.Split(new char[] {','});
            switch(splitArray[0])
            {
                case "Delivery No.":
                    deliverNo = splitArray[8];
                    break;
                case "W No.":
                    wNo = splitArray[8];
                    break;
                case "Manufacturer":
                    manufacturer = splitArray[8];
                    break;
                case "Diameter":
                    diameter = splitArray[8];
                    break;
                case "Poly-type/Conductivity":
                    pTypeConductivity = splitArray[8];
                    break;
                case "face/Orientation":
                    faceOrientation = splitArray[8];
                    break;
                case "Surface Finish":
                    surfaceFinish = splitArray[8];
                    break;
                case "Ave.":
                    average = decimal.Parse(splitArray[13]);
                    break;
                case "Uniformity(sigma/Ave.)":
                    uniformityAve = decimal.Parse(splitArray[13]);
                    uniformitySigma = decimal.Parse(splitArray[21]);
                    break;
                case "MAX":
                    max = decimal.Parse(splitArray[13]);
                    break;
                case "MIN":
                    min = decimal.Parse(splitArray[13]);
                    break;
            }
        }
     }
    public class Part
    {
        public string part { get; set; }
        public decimal thinkness { get; set; }
        public List<Tuple<decimal, decimal, decimal>> points { get; set; }
        decimal lastThinkness = 0;

        public void AddPoint(string line)
        {
            if (points == null) points = new List<Tuple<decimal, decimal, decimal>>();
            string[] splitArray = line.Split(new char[] { ',' });
            decimal x = decimal.Parse(splitArray[1]);
            decimal y = decimal.Parse(splitArray[5]);
            decimal thickness = (splitArray[12] == "-") ? lastThinkness : decimal.Parse(splitArray[12]);
            lastThinkness = thickness;
            Tuple<decimal, decimal, decimal> point = Tuple.Create(x,y,thickness);

            points.Add(point);
        }
    }

}
```